# Puppet installs too many dependencies

Tags: puppet

I have a puppet class 'php' which looks like the following:

```
    class php {
  case $operatingsystem {
    debian: {
      package {'php5-common':
        ensure => latest,
        provider => apt,
       }
      package {'php5-mysql': ensure => latest, provider => apt}
      package {'php5-gd': ensure => latest, provider => apt}
      package {'php5-fpm': ensure => latest, provider => apt}
      package {'php5-mcrypt': ensure => latest, provider => apt}
      package {'php5-memcache': ensure => latest, provider => apt}
    }
  }

  service { 'php5-fpm':
    ensure => running,
    enable => true,
  }
}
```

I include the php class in the node configuration in /etc/puppet/manifests/site.pp

It looks like

```
node 'example' {
  include php
}
```

When I run puppet agent -t on the client it installs the packages, but it installs kind of too much. It also installs apache and I don't know where it gets it from. I don't have any config in puppet for apache.

I guess it's using the debian recommendations or suggestions, but I'm not sure, because
I disabled that on the server.

```
cat > /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/01norecommend 

The log output on the client is


Info: Retrieving plugin
Info: Loading facts in /var/lib/puppet/lib/facter/pe_version.rb
Info: Loading facts in /var/lib/puppet/lib/facter/puppet_vardir.rb
Info: Loading facts in /var/lib/puppet/lib/facter/last_run.rb
Info: Loading facts in /var/lib/puppet/lib/facter/root_home.rb
Info: Loading facts in /var/lib/puppet/lib/facter/puppi_projects.rb
Info: Loading facts in /var/lib/puppet/lib/facter/facter_dot_d.rb
Info: Caching catalog for eample
Info: Applying configuration version '1383041633'
Error: Could not prefetch package provider 'apt': invalid byte sequence in US-ASCII
Notice: /Stage[main]/Php/Package[php5-mysql]/ensure: ensure changed 'purged' to 'latest'
Notice: /Stage[main]/Php/Package[php5-gd]/ensure: ensure changed 'purged' to 'latest'
Notice: /Stage[main]/Php/Package[php5-mcrypt]/ensure: ensure changed 'purged' to 'latest'
Notice: /Stage[main]/Php/Package[php5-memcache]/ensure: ensure changed 'purged' to 'latest'
Notice: /Stage[main]/Php/Package[php5-fpm]/ensure: ensure changed 'purged' to 'latest'
Notice: Finished catalog run in 11.31 seconds



The following packages are installed after that


ii  apache2-mpm-prefork                2.2.22-13 amd64        Apache HTTP Server - traditional non-threaded model
ii  apache2-utils                      2.2.22-13 amd64        utility programs for webservers
ii  apache2.2-bin                      2.2.22-13 amd64        Apache HTTP Server common binary files
ii  apache2.2-common                   2.2.22-13 amd64        Apache HTTP Server common files
ii  libapache2-mod-php5filter          5.4.4-14+deb7u5 amd64        server-side, HTML-embedded scripting language (apache 2 filter module)
ii  libapache2-mod-php5filter          5.4.4-14+deb7u5 amd64        server-side, HTML-embedded scripting language (apache 2 filter module)
ii  php5-common                        5.4.4-14+deb7u5 amd64        Common files for packages built from the php5 source
ii  php5-fpm                           5.4.4-14+deb7u5 amd64        server-side, HTML-embedded scripting language (FPM-CGI binary)
ii  php5-gd                            5.4.4-14+deb7u5 amd64        GD module for php5
ii  php5-mcrypt                        5.4.4-14+deb7u5 amd64        MCrypt module for php5
ii  php5-memcache                      3.0.6-6 amd64        memcache extension module for PHP5
ii  php5-mysql                         5.4.4-14+deb7u5 amd64        MySQL module for php5
```

When I run apt-get install $php-package-names it won't install apache, just when I use apache. That's kind of annoying, because I'm going to use nginx.

Do you have an idea how I can get puppet to install the packages normally without apache as dependency?

Comment: Could you check reverse dependencies with "apt-get rdepends <package>"?
There might be some traces there.

Comment: Thanks, the problem is solved now. apt-rdepends showed traces to phpapi-20100525, a virtual package.

aptitude show phpapi-20100525 outputs:
Provided by: libapache2-mod-php5, libapache2-mod-php5filter, libphp5-embed, php5-cgi, php5-cli, php5-fpm

As Shane already wrote it will use the first one, in this case libapache2-mod-php5.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make `php5-fpm` install before the others with `require`.

The `gd`, `memcache`, `mcrypt`, and `mysql` packages require the virtual package `phpapi-20100525`, which is provided by `libapache2-mod-php5` or by `php5-fpm`.

When you install them in a single command, it's already installing one of the packages that fulfills the requirement.  When run separately as Puppet resources, apt is forced to pick one and picks the Apache library.

Comment: Thanks, that solved the problem. I'd upvote you, but I just signed up yesterday and it requires at least 15 reputation.